# oracle declare variable integer to be used as counter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could anyone show me an example how you would run this type of MySQL style query in Oracle?

```
SET @counter = 0;

SELECT (@counter+1) AS rowCount, t.username FROM USER AS t
```

I've seen various examples showing DECLARE or DEFINE and things like

```
DECLARE
counter SMALLINT := 0;

SELECT (counter+1) AS rowCount, t.username FROM USER AS t
```

but none of them seem to work, I just keep getting errors about thing like *'Error starting at line 1 in command:'* (not very helpful!).

Regards

KS

Comment: What do you want the `rowCount` to show; if `username` is unique in `USER` (which is a reserved word and a bad choice for a table name) then are you expecting that to always be one? Or do you want each row returned by a query to be numbered sequentially? Or do you want the counter to increment as you run multiple queries?

Comment: In your posted code this looks like `rownum`...

Comment: Oracle has ROWNUM for this. `select ROWNUM as rowCount, username from USER`

Comment: I would like the rowCount to increment but ultimately I'm looking to use the value of username substr (0,5) to be concatenated with this rowCount to produce a new unique value that I have been asked to provide. So msmith would become msmit1, ajackson would become ajack2, ewillson becomes ewils3 etc etc etc

Comment: @Noel - Unbelievable! How the hell have I not seen an example using ROWNUM!!!! Cheers.

Comment: @Passerby - See you too have spotted this ROWNUM answer. cheer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECLARE` is the start on an anonymous PL/SQL block, and your `SELECT` needs to be in the block too, between a `BEGIN` and `END`. But you also need to select into something.

If you just want to see a sequential row count across the selected rows you can use the [`rownum` pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns009.htm):

```
SELECT rownum AS rowCount, t.username FROM USER t
```

(You can't use `AS t` either, you can only use `AS` to alias columns...)

This approach would work for your end goal, and you can concatenate the `substr` with the `rownum`

```
SELECT rownum AS rowCount, t.username,
    substr(t.username, 1, 5) || rownum as newname
FROM USER t
```

But really don't use a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_keywd001.htm) as a table name.

Comment: Cheers, seems ROWNUM is the way to go, just tested it and it gives me what I'm looking for. cheers.      Note:Yep agreed USER is a bad table name, but the table has been around for about 5 years so we're kind of stuck with it (before my time)

Comment: @KPS-UK: you might also want to look into `row_number()` which gives you a better control over the ordering which the numbers are assigned.